# git push ssh on ubuntu 'Please make sure you have the correct access rights'

Tags: git, permissions

This is what I did:

I cloned a git repo of code challenge from its `https` link first.

```
git clone https://github.com/user-name/code-challenge.git
```

I created a local branch on my local machine, added the files and committed.
Next I tried to push it to the local branch,

```
git push -u origin mycode_solution
```

I got following error:

```
remote: Permission to user-name/code-challenge.git denied to JohnDoe.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user-name/code-challenge.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Then I tried on of the solution to already submitted similar question i.e by changing the git remote url:

Earlier it was `https` url:
Now I changed it to `ssh` url by doing

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user-name/code-challenge.git
```

I added my local ssh `id_rsa.pub` key to the github.

Then I again I tried pushing:

```
git push -u origin mycode_solution
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Permission to user-name/code-challenge.git denied to JohnDoe.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What else is there to try?

Answer (score 1):

Things to be checked:

1. You need to configure your keys to GitHub in order to access the repository.
2. Whoever may be the owner, the need to give permissions to push changes to the repo or branch.

Are these done?

Comment: I have added my keys to github.
The owner hasnt given any.

Comment: If you are the owner.. you must be able to do all the changes.. else can you please check with the repo's owner?

Comment: @user3576036 So the repo's owner hasn't given you permissions to push changes to the repo, and now you're wondering why you can't push changes to the repo?